Derivative in information/rate theory
I am trying to understand how to obtain the following derivation w.r.t. $p(\hat{x}|x)$ but cannot for the life of me find out how they do.
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial p(\hat{x}|x)} \left( \sum \sum p(x)p(\hat{x}|x)\log\left(\frac{p(\hat{x}|x)}{p(\hat{x})}\right) \right) = p(x)\left(\log\left(\frac{p(\hat{x}|x)}{p(\hat{x})}\right)+1-\frac{1}{p(\hat{x})}p(x)p(\hat{x}|x)\right).$$
So, I get that we can rewrite the expression to the following:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial p(\hat{x}|x)} \left( \sum \sum p(x)p(\hat{x}|x)\log\left(\frac{p(\hat{x}|x)}{p(\hat{x})}\right) \right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial p(\hat{x}|x)} \left( \sum \sum p(x)p(\hat{x}|x)\log(p(\hat{x}|x)) - \sum \sum p(x)p(\hat{x}|x)\log(p(\hat{x})) \right),$$
And then we get by derivating the first term w.r.t. $p(\hat{x}|x)$ the following:
$$(1) \frac{\partial}{\partial p(\hat{x}|x)} \left( \sum \sum p(x)p(\hat{x}|x)\log(p(\hat{x}|x))\right)=p(x)log(p(\hat{x}|x))+p(x).$$
That part seems correct. The problem arises when I try to derivate the second term w.r.t. $p(\hat{x}|x)$, then I get the following:
$$(2) \frac{\partial}{\partial p(\hat{x}|x)} \left(- \sum \sum p(x)p(\hat{x}|x)\log(p(\hat{x})\right)=-p(x)\log(p(\hat{x})).$$
This does not give me the correct answer, and it seems like they also derivate $p(\hat{x})$ in some way in order to get the correct answer. My question is why, isn't $p(\hat{x})$ seen as a constant here? This subject have been discussed in a similar subject Functional Derivative Rate distortion theory, however they do not explain why they derivate the second term in two parts.

I believe they use the following fact
$p(\hat{x}|x)=\frac{p(\hat{x},x)}{p(x)}$, therefore $p(\hat{x},x)=p(x)p(\hat{x}|x)$, and $p(\hat{x})=\sum_{x'}p(x')p(\hat{x}|x').$ Therefore $\frac{\partial p(\hat{x})}{p(\hat{x}|x)}=p(x)$ and you get their expression.
